# Rake task to migrate tenants on their schema's on multiple darabases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-schema, rake-task, apartment-gem, multi-database

i'm iterating on my tenants list in apartment and running the migration under each tenant i discovered that the migration task running only one time in my case just for the first tenant

```
namespace :db do
  desc 'Run migrations or rollback for all tenants in a multi-server setup'

  task :multi_server, [:task_to_run] => :environment do |_, args|
    task_to_run = args[:task_to_run]

    unless task_to_run.present?
      puts 'Please specify a task to run (e.g., db:migrate, db:rollback, etc.)'
      exit(1)
    end

    Apartment::tenants_with_config.each do |tenant_name, db_config|
      if db_config.present?
        if db_config['database'] == 'primary'
          puts "Running '#{task_to_run}' for the primary database directly."
          # Rake::Task[task_to_run].reenable # Re-enable the task
          Rake::Task[task_to_run].invoke # Invoke the task again
          puts "#{task_to_run.capitalize} completed for the primary database."
        else
          begin
            # Establish the connection to the tenant's database using Apartment's configuration
            ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_config)

            # Log that the connection is successfully established
            puts '======================================='
            puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
            # Log tenant-specific information
            puts '======================================='
            # Switch to the tenant's schema (assuming you're using PostgreSQL schemas)
            # Apartment::Tenant.switch(tenant_name) do
            #   puts "Switched to schema for tenant: #{tenant_name}"
            # Run the specified task for this tenant
            puts "Running '#{task_to_run} ' for tenant: #{tenant_name}"
            # output = %x{RAILS_ENV=develzopment rails db:migrate 2>&1} # Run and capture output

            # Load Rake tasks dynamically for the current tenant

           puts  Rake::Task[task_to_run].invoke
           puts Rake::Task[task_to_run].reenable


            #system('RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace')
            puts "#{task_to_run.capitalize} completed for tenant: #{tenant_name}"
          rescue StandardError => e
            puts "Error establishing connection for tenant: #{tenant_name}"
            puts "Error message: #{e.message}"
          ensure
            # Reset the connection to the primary database after running the task
            ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:primary)
          end
        end
      else
        puts "No database configuration found for tenant: #{tenant_name}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJl6V.png)

the migration task running only one time in my case just for the first tenant while i was expecting that it will run for each tenant on their database

Comment: Check the console logs. Based on the console logs screenshot it couldn't find the next schema/tenant `bmw`, hence it raised an exception and stopped.

Comment: i try to catch that error using rescue StandardError => e but it didn't catch it